# How to Create Thumbnails in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a video player app for android. for that i need to create thumbnails for the videos present in the videos folder.

After searching web i could able to understand unity's MovieTexture doesn't support for android. This one i could able to solve using a plugin.

For creating thumbnails i planned to create a canvas, and load GUI objects at runtime from prefab. create "GUI Raw Image" with images that would be the thumbnail image representing the video.

My hard luck, i came to understand GUI Raw Image is non trigger object. So changed to use GUI buttons instead of Raw Images.

But the issue, i am not able to attach image to my button prefab.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your image imported as a Texture or a Sprite2D?

Comment: @Savlon , i have imported as sprite2D after searching docs. and finally able to solve the issue.

Comment: @Savlon if you add your comment as answer, i will mark it as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the new UI objects, as opposed to the Legacy GUI, you must have the image imported as Sprite/UI.

[Unity Import Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)